# Program for binary to decimal conversion in C isn't working like it's supposed to and instead gives some random outputs

Tags: arrays, c, binary

The program is supposed to ask for length and number of binary arrays and then stores them and converts them all into decimal and prints the decimal part. The logic seems fine to me but it isn't working for some reason and gives weird outputs. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {  
    int n, decimal_num = 0, base = 1, rem;  
    printf ("Enter the length and number of binary strings: ");
    scanf(" %i", &n);  
    int str[n], deci[n];
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("Enter string %i: ", i + 1);
        scanf(" %i", &str[i]); 
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        while (str[i] > 0) {  
            rem = str[i] % 10; 
            decimal_num = decimal_num + rem * base;  
            str[i] = str[i] / 10;
            base = base * 2;
        }
        deci[i]= decimal_num;
        decimal_num= 0;
    }  
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%i\n", deci[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not see any strings here

Comment: You are reading integers instead of what it looks like supposed to be bits. And then it is not clear what `n` is supposed to signify

Comment: You don't set decimal_num to 0 between conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues I see with this program. First off creating arrays the way you did will give errors with most compilers. This is fixed by dynamically allocating the arrays by including stdlib.h and using malloc

```
int *str, *deci;
str = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
deci = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

This also means you would need to free this memory at the end at the end of your program.

```
free(str);
free(deci);
```

The second issue is in the second loop calculating the base 10 values. This is most likely what is causing the incorrect output. The issue is caused by not resetting the base variable after each iteration of the loop. This is causing the program to interpret the binary numbers at much larger than they actually are. This can be fixed by setting the `base` variable back to one in the same place you are setting `decimal_num` to zero

Another issue which doesn't affect functionality is the naming of your variables. More specifically the variable `str` which doesn't store a string. You should rename this to something more descriptive e.g. `binary_nums`. I would also recommend renaming `deci` for the same reason.

Additionally I was also getting issues with the `scanf` call using `%i` in the first loop so I changed it to `%d` which fixed the issue for me.

The fixed program looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
    int n, decimal_num = 0, base = 1, rem;
    int *binary_nums, *base10_nums;
    printf("Enter the length and number of binary strings: ");
    scanf(" %d", &n);
    binary_nums = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    base10_nums = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Enter string %i: ", i + 1);
        scanf(" %d", &binary_nums[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        while (binary_nums[i] > 0) {
            rem = binary_nums[i] % 10;
            decimal_num = decimal_num + rem * base;
            binary_nums[i] = binary_nums[i] / 10;
            base = base * 2;
        }
        base10_nums[i] = decimal_num;
        decimal_num = 0;
        base = 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%i\n", base10_nums[i]);
    }
    free(binary_nums);
    free(base10_nums);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned conv(const char *binaryString)
{
    unsigned result = 0;

    while(binaryString && *binaryString)
    {
        if(*binaryString == '\n') break;
        result *= 2;
        result += *binaryString++ == '1';
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    int size, number;

    scanf("%u", &size);
    scanf("%u", &number);
    /* check return value of scanf */

    char strings[number][size+1];

    for(int n = 0; n < number; )
    {   
        fgets(strings[n], size, stdin);
        /* add error checks */
        if(strings[n++][0] == '\n') n--;
    }

    for(int n = 0; n < number; n++)
    {
        printf("%u (0x%x) == %s", conv(strings[n]), conv(strings[n]), strings[n]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do exactly?  I ran it, but I think the newlines here are messing up flow of execution.  Maybe a `strings[strcspn(strings, "\n")] = 0;` after each `fgets` ?

Comment: This answer could use some explanation.